# How to Edit Polymorphic Comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, comments, polymorphic-associations

Since comments are being posted in multiple locations: habits, goals, etc. What path do I use to edit the comment in comments/_comments?

I tried:

```
<%= link_to edit_comment_path(comment) do %> #Or should we use conditionals to target: edit_habit_comment_path, edit_goal_comment_path, etc?
  <%= comment.content %>
<% end %>
```

But upon clicking on it we get this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=2 [WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = ? AND "comments"."commentable_type" = ?])

I played around with what to put in `def edit` here:

**comments_controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :load_commentable
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

    def index
        @comments = @commentable.comments
    end

    def new
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new
    end

    def create
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
        if @comment.save
            redirect_to @commentable, notice: "comment created."
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
    @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @habit
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
        if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
            redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment was updated."
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to @commentable, notice: "comment destroyed."
    end

  def like
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
    if @comment_like.save
            @comment.increment!(:likes)
        flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
        flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
      end  
        redirect_to(:back)
  end

private

  def set_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

    def load_commentable
        resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
        @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
    end

    def comment_params
        params[:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commentable, :user_id, :like)
    end
end
```

I closely followed this tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised

Please let me know if you need further explanation or code to help you help me :)

### UPDATE

I tried a lot of alternatives for the **routes**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'notes/index'

  get 'notes/new'

  get 'notifications/index'

  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#facebook'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  resources :users do
    resources :comments
  end

  shallow do
    resources :habits do
      resources :comments
    end
    resources :goals do
      resources :comments
    end
  end


  resources :notes

  resources :habits do
    resources :notes
    resources :notifications
    resources :comments do
      resources :likes
    end
    resources :likes
    member do
      post :like
      post :notifications
    end
    resources :levels do
      # we'll use this route to increment and decrement the missed days
      resources :days_missed, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end

  resources :goals do
    resources :notes
    resources :comments
    member do
      post :like
    end
  end

  resources :valuations do
    resources :notes
    resources :comments
    resources :notifications
    member do
      post :like
      post :notifications
    end
  end

  resources :quantifieds do
    resources :notes
    resources :comments
    member do
      post :like
    end
  end

  resources :results

  resources :users

  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]

  resources :activities do
    resources :valuations
    resources :comments
    resources :notifications
    member do
      post :like
      post :notifications
    end
  end

  resources :comments do
    resources :comments
    member do
      post :like
    end
  end

  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]

  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'pages#home', as: :tag

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  get    'about'   => 'pages#about'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  root 'pages#home'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find [shallow nested routes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) useful. Basically, you write

```
shallow do
  resources :goals do
    resources :comments
  end

  # ...
end
```

which is equivalent to

```
resources :goals do
  resources :comments, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
resources :comments, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# ...
```

This means, only those actions which absolutely need the nesting will actually be nested. If you just want to show, edit, update, or destroy a comment, it will work like any other non-nested resource and you will be able to simply use `edit_comment_path`.

You will need to change your controller accordingly, because the `commentable_id` (i.e. `goal_id`) will not be part of the url any more. You can still get to the commentable via `@comment.commentable` (for redirection). The cleanest solution I have come across to setting the commentable in the comments controller is to look for the name of the `:commentable_id` in `params`, as opposed to fiddling around with the request path. This would result in a controller like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_commentable, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :like]

  def index
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  def new
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
      redirect_to @comment.commentable, notice: "Comment was updated."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to @comment.commentable, notice: "Comment destroyed."
  end

  def like
    @comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
    if @comment_like.save
      @comment.increment!(:likes)
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Too many likes'
    end  
    redirect_to(:back)
  end

  private

  def set_commentable
    @commentable = find_commentable
  end

  # add more commentable models here
  def find_commentable
    if params[:goal_id]
      Goal.find(params[:goal_id])
    elsif params[:habit_id]
      Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    else
      fail 'Unsupported commentable'
    end
  end

  def set_comment
    @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def comment_params
    params[:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commentable, :user_id, :like)
  end
end
```

Comment: I have corrected some minor things in your controller, you might learn something from carefully going over each action. Sorry if I left some mistakes in there, I have no time to really test this right now. Just let me know and I'll do my best to correct them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful answer :) I've spent some time now trying to understand it with my beginners mindset. With your controller code and my updated routes (see question update) I am confronted with the same pesky error as in the question with the line pointing to: `@comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])`  when clicking `link_to edit_comment_path(comment)`

Comment: Well the error suggests that there is no comment that satisfies the query. The commentable id and type should however have disappeared from the error. Have you made sure a comment with the requested id actually exists?

Comment: I reset the database Patrick and made one comment then clicked on it: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#edit
Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=1 [WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = ? AND "comments"."commentable_type" = ?]` pointing to `@comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])` Maybe I have to change the _form or _comments iteration?

Comment: _form: `<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>` _comments: `<% @comments.each do |comment| %>`? Thanks Patrick! :)

Comment: So that error happens inside `set_comment`, right? With the code I've seen so far, I cannot explain how commentable_id and commentable_type made it into the query, because they're not explicitly referenced in set_comment. Maybe you have a default scope set in your Comment model? How did you define the User - Comment association? Both of these might add the implicit commentable attributes to all Comment queries.

Comment: You are the man. You were right about the models. I had to get rid of `has_many :comments, as: :commentable` and add the ids to the database columns. Thanks again Patrick!